# How can I remove the Review step in Onepage checkout in Magento?

Tags: magento, checkout

I would like the order to be processed after the Payment method step. If payment method selected then payment cycle should complete instead of Review Orders step.

I have followed the steps from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/how-can-i-remove-the-review-step-in-onepage-checkout
but it stuck on the payment page and not able to place the order.

Please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps in this [post](https://nikunjvadariya.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/magento-how-to-combinemerge-payment-method-and-review-step-in-one-step/) and it was worked for me.

The above post helps you to combine Payment and Review steps in to one step. If you want to take out the order review information in payment step, comment the code in checkout.xml (in Your theme's Layout), comment the code between the following comments
 and

Also, you need to change the button label for Payment Form from **Continue** to **Place Order**
you can find this button in frontend/default/theme/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

Comment: Thank you for this answer.
It merged the Payment Method and Review Steps, Now I am able to see two buttons on the Payment Method step. One is continue and other is Place Order Button. When I click on Continue button it is taking me to next (Review) Step and if I click on Place Order Button nothing happens.

Comment: It was worked for me. I have takeout the place order Button and rename the text on Continue button to Place Order. When i click on continue, the order was placed and is redirected to success page. It worked with Magento default themes default and rwd (Magento version 1.9.0.1)

Comment: Hello Rajendra can you please tell me which line should I comment in checkout.xml. I have used this code however, it is redirecting me to cart page.

Comment: where is checkout.xml? I'm pretty new to magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some modules, which allow this functionality. E.g.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-checkout.html

> Disable unnecessary checkout fields and steps for a more compact faster checkout!

Answer (score 0):

Magento: How to combine/merge payment method and review step in one step
https://nikunjvadariya.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/magento-how-to-combinemerge-payment-method-and-review-step-in-one-step/comment-page-1/#comment-517

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because the page may be removed. Please inline the relevant information directly in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, I have followed the instructions as per the link however, it redirects me to cart page after selecting the Delivery Time.

Comment: @byako OK by the comment